# Some of My Input Fields Are Not Submitting

Tags: javascript, forms, stripe-payments, submit

I'm using Stripe for my payment gateway. After I request and receive the token, I then attempt to submit the form to my server.

The problem is; only the token is posting back. I want to catch the email address as well. When I step through, the form's input values are all properly set when I call `form.submit()` .

So - I'm wondering what I need to be looking for here. Is there an attribute that keeps an element's data from being submitted? I'm slightly confused as to why the only field returning to my server is the stripe token.

The form is completely filled out, but after token retrieval, something is kicked back to me that causes everything else to get ghosted.

It's gotta be some property or attribute I'm not aware of - but no google search is revealing anything.

Please don't flag me for not being specific enough - this is as specific as I can get without dumping a meg of DOM hierarchy at you guys.

Thanks in advance to anybody who can point me in the right direction.

Comment: A couple possibilities: "the only field returning to my server is the stripe token." . Are you sure? (#1) If you haven't done this, then use your browsers Inspector, and on the "Network" tab, look at the "POST" being done, and see what your submitted values are according to your browser, not the server. (#2) Is the post done via a form action attribute: <form action="/submit_page.hmtl"> or via some custom .js? If it's done via custom .js, then look there. JS can manipulate what is being POSTed.

Comment: That's actually a good point. I haven't checked the client side post values. Well - I mean, not from the network tab. I'll take a look - thanks

Comment: Ya, it's only sending the token. I'm going to have to step through everything again. I can't for the life of me see anything that would be stripping that data or "turning it off" - if there is such a thing. Maybe I should just build a js form, mount it, and submit that one instead. I'll be sure to post what is happening when I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is beyond me.
So - here's my fix. I ended up building a new form programatically, re-appending the data as children, and submitting it.
I honestly have no idea what the problem is - but this is a deadline-fix.

```
var formPost = document.createElement("form");
    formPost.setAttribute('method','post');

  var eToken = document.createElement('input');
  eToken.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  eToken.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  eToken.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  formPost.appendChild(eToken);

    var eName = document.createElement('input');
  eName.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  eName.setAttribute('name', 'name');
  eName.setAttribute('value', document.getElementById("paxyz-name").value);
  formPost.appendChild(eName);

    var eEmail = document.createElement('input');
  eEmail.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  eEmail.setAttribute('name', 'email');
  eEmail.setAttribute('value', document.getElementById("paxyz-email").value);
  formPost.appendChild(eEmail);

    var ePhone = document.createElement('input');
  ePhone.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  ePhone.setAttribute('name', 'phone');
  ePhone.setAttribute('value', document.getElementById("paxyz-phone").value);
  formPost.appendChild(ePhone);

    var eZip = document.createElement('input');
  eZip.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  eZip.setAttribute('name', 'zip');
  eZip.setAttribute('value', document.getElementById("paxyz-zip").value);
  formPost.appendChild(eZip);

    document.body.appendChild(formPost);

  // Submit the form
  formPost.submit();
```